# Retrieving messages from a user id in mysql/php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, chat

Since my last question was very vague, I figured I would clear some things up. I am learning how to build a private chat application (for educational reasons only), and I am trying to figure out the best way to do a private chat. I created a 2 tables, `user` and `chat`. In `chat`, I have 5 columns:

- message_id
- user_id
- username
- message
- send

I want to retrieve only the messages from the selected `user_id`.

Right now, here is my send form. Input name send = the data I want to retrieve. Until I get the hang of things, I only want to retrieve the `user_id` number (so you would put a number in the text area to chat to that username).

```
<form name="form" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="send" id="send" value="">
    <input name="user_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id'];?>" id="user_id">
    <textarea name="message" class="message" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('submit').click()"></textarea>
    <input type="submit"  name="Submit" id="submit" value="">
</form>
```

And here is my php retrieval form

```
<?php
class Chat extends Core {
   public function fetchMessages() {
        $this->query("
        SELECT          chat.message,
                        users.username,
                        users.user_id,
                        chat.send
        FROM            chat
        JOIN            users
        ON              chat.user_id //and chat.send = users.user_id 
        ORDER BY        chat.timestamp
        DESC
    ");

    return $this->rows();
   }

}
```

Basically, I want to set a condition to something like:

```
<?php
$send=$_POST['send'];
$userid=$_POST['user_id'];
if ($send == $userid || (isset($_POST['user_id']))) //this isn't correct- just trying to    display my though
{
    //retrieve message from user_id number in sql table, allowing the people that have the same user_id as send to only read the message.
}   
?>
```

So basically, how can I only retrieve the information for a specific user_id number, and where would I place this condition?

Comment: @Mihai action defaults to the current URL, so you don't need it if the processing code is in the same script as the code to display the form.

Comment: @Barmar But you don't need it set to empty in this case?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you want to match on: `user_id` or `send`?

Comment: @Mihai No, if you leave it out it's the same as `action=""`.

Comment: basically if your user_id = send (on the retrieval side), you can read the message. If not, you will never be able to see that message the message.

Comment: I have an ajax code that sends the form to my php page. It is just irrelevant for this question.

Comment: i also wonder, why are you going to post the session user id in a post... u already got it saved in the session, so you can call it instead of $_POST..

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. I think all you need to do is `if ($_POST['send'] == $_SESSION['user_id'])`, it doesn't need to be in the query.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you mean but if you want to get messages from a specific userid, you could do something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['getMsgsById']) && isset($_POST['userid'])){
  $userid = (int)$_POST['userid'];

  $chat = new Chat(); // 


  if(!$msgs = $chat->getMsgsByUserId($userid)){
       echo "No messages found";
  }else{
      $length = count($msgs);

      for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
          echo $msgs[$i]['msg']. '<br />';
      }

  }
}


class Chat{

   public function getMsgsByUserId($id){
       $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM your_message_table WHERE userid=$id");
       if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
            return array();

       while($info = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
           $arr[] = $info;
       }

       return $arr;
   }

}
```

Ofcourse this is just something very fast.

Comment: Thanks! I am going to tweak a bit, and I will post it, once I am done. But this is what I was looking for.